# 400 Code When Trying to Send Patch to API

Tags: python, api, rest, flask

I have an access system that provides a REST API and I am very new to playing with them. I'm using python with Flask to show some of the data which works fine. I'm attempting to use a patch request to update the email off a cardholder.

**UPDATE**

```
data = {
    "personalDataDefinitions": [{
        "@Email": {
            "value": "test@test.com"
        }}]
}

r = requests.put(url, json=data, headers=headers, verify=ssl.CERT_NONE)
```

Changing the request to a put request and 'json=data' seems to have worked. Patch requests still doesn't work, it produces a 204 error.

**My Code**

```
@app.route('/update', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update():
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'MY KEY GOSE HERE',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)'}
    url = 'https://10.0.0.74:8904/api/cardholders/695'
    data = {
        "@Email": {
            "value": "test@test.com"
        }
    }

    r = requests.patch(url, data=data, headers=headers, verify=ssl.CERT_NONE)
    print(r.status_code, r.reason)
    return render_template('update.html')
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as I always get a 400 Bad Request.
There is open documentation for this at https://gallaghersecurity.github.io/cc-rest-docs/ref/cardholders.html#definition-Cardholder-detail

Comment: From the documentation link I can see that the `@email` value should be under `personalDataDefinitions`. Not sure if it is the only thing but could be related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
r = requests.patch(url, json=data, headers=headers, verify=ssl.CERT_NONE)
```

Comment: This produces a 204 error, so we're onto something.

Comment: For some reason I had to PUT first even though data already existed and after that I was able to patch. So this seems to be the issue. Thanks for the suggeston!

Comment: missed you last comment, but glad you fixed it :)